# Static equilibrium

Tags: mechanical-engineering, torque

I am trying to find the angle theta when the system is in static equilibrium but I have some difficulties in setting up my equation due to the extra arm for F1.
Can someone help me to set up the equilibrium equation to find the angle?

I know the length from the pivot point O to F1 and F2 and the angle between the wall and the horizontal line is 52 degrees.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *extra arm* ? Both $F2$ and $F1$ are drawn with an offset from *plade*. What are the lengths of the offsets ?

Comment: The force F1 is acting on an arm perpendicular to the plate Shouldn't this be taken into account? 
If we call the offset Lx1 and Lx2

Comment: Yes. But in your question, you seem to imply that $F1$ has an *extra* arm while $F2$ doesn't. Can you edit the figure to show the distances that are known to you ?

Comment: I see, the figure is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: angles marked]

Let $LL1 \triangleq \sqrt{L1^2 + L1x^2}$. This quantity is fixed.

Lets work with the vertical as our reference (and forget about the 52 deg wall till the end). The angle between the mass and the plate is
$
\tan^{-1}(L1x/L1)
$.

So $\phi = \tan^{-1}(L1x/L1) - \psi$.

Moment about $O$ due to $m_1$ is $F1 \cdot LL1 \sin(\phi)$. Substitute for $\phi$. Here, the only unknown is $\psi$.

After writing down expressions for moment for the plate and $m_2$, equate them, and solve for $\psi$. Convert the result to $\theta$.

Comment: Take care of the *sign* of the moments.

Comment: How would you set up the equilibrium torque equation ?

Comment: As shown above, write down the epxression for the three moments, say $M_1$, $M_2$, $M_{plade}$ with appropriate signs. Equilibrium equation would be $M_1 + M_2 + M_{plade} = 0$. Only unknown in that equation should be $\psi$.